# Recursion, Sigma Notation (html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

my objective is to use recursion to get sigma notation working.  top limit is n(input variable) bottom limit is i=1, and the function is (-i)^(i-1).  i got it working with iteration but i cant get the recursion to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Recursion</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Recursion</h1>
<script = "text/javascript">
var num
var i;
var n;
var total;
total = 0;
i=0;
var b;
b=0;
function formula(n)
{
(Math.pow((-i),(i-1)))
}

function recursion(n)
{
i=i+1;
if ((n-i) == 0)
{
document.writeln("done");
}
else
{
total = total + recursion(formula(n-i));
return total;

//total = total + (Math.pow((-i),(i-1)) + recursion(n-i));
}
}
num = window.prompt("pick a number");
recursion(num);
document.writeln(recursion(num));
//document.writeln(total);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: waaaay to crash my browser dude

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid any global variables, that makes it very hard to read. Also, indent your code properly; and don't mix the output (`document.write`) into the computation. If you don't understand the recursion, just use a loop:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i=1; i<=n; i++)
    total += formula(i);
return total; // the result
```

The same thing, done with recursion:

```
function sumFormulaUpTo (n) {
    if (n <= 0) // the abort condition
        return 0;
    else
        return sumFormulaUpTo(n-1) + formula(n);
}
sumFormulaUpTo(100);
```

You notice: there is no `total` variable, only the result of the recursively called function is used.

With an end recursion (more like the loop), it would look like this:

```
function sumFormulaFromTo(total, i, n) {
    if ( i > n )
        return total;
    else {
        var newtotal = total + formula(i);
        return sumFormulaFromTo(newtotal, i+1, n);
    }
}
sumFormulaFromTo(0, 1, 100);
```

If you had `total` and `n` declared statically outside the function, it would look more like yours. Yet, you forgot to return the result once the end condition is met (you just output something, but return `undefined`), and you somehow called the recursion with the result of `formula` - no idea where you got that from. This causes an infinite loop, according to @cbayram.

Comment: @Alex, to add to this rewrite your formula function so it returns a value and function parameter name matches up to what you are using. **function formula(x)
{
 return Math.pow((-x),(x-1)));
}**

Comment: @cbayram: No, `<= 0` (or `< 1`) is correct - you want to execute the `formula` for `n==1`, for everything lower than that the sum is `0`

Comment: @cbayram: thanks for your hints regarding the correctness of the summation. I should've checked all of the end conditions :-) - fixed now

Comment: You gave a great answer, please don't take any offense, I was just fact checking a bit to maintain the integrity of your answer.

Comment: actually im getting NaN now as a result

Comment: [Worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/ffvWX/), you must be doing something wrong. Or you're trying to get a sum from more `formula` invokations than your `maximum call stack size` - another reason to use a loop

Comment: im trying to do the second one.  the one with recursion

Comment: Your `formula` does not return anything (resulting into NaN when added to 0), has an argument which is not used, but uses one of those unnecessary global variables (`i`). The stackoverflow is likely because you picked a too big number